# Diferencia TryParse Convert y keyword out

Tags: c#, cast, casting

Estoy manteniendo código y me he encontrado esta sentencia. Nunca había usado este método.

```
int.TryParse(DataRow["Zona"].ToString(), out nZona);
```

Como siempre, cuando veo código que nunca he usado me entra curiosidad.

¿Es lo mismo si yo hago lo siguiente?

```
int nZona = Convert.ToInt32(DataRow["Zona"].ToString());
```

¿Existe alguna diferencia entre `int.TryParse` y `Convert.ToInt32`? si es así, ¿Que ventajas o desventajas tiene el uno respecto al otro? o ¿En que caso me convendría usar uno en vez de otro?

¿la palabra reservada `out` modifica directamente el valor como si estuviera haciendo un `byval` en `visual basic`? ¿Que diferencia hay entre hacer `out variable` o `variable = sentencia`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ¿Existe alguna diferencia entre `int.TryParse` y `Convert.ToInt32`?

¡Muchas!

`int.TryParse`.

Su objetivo es intentar (try) interpretar (parse) una cadena de texto como un dato de tipo `int`, devuelve una variable booleana para indicar si lo consiguió o no.

- Devuelve `bool`.
- Tiene dos sobrecargas.

  - Una cadena y un `int`.
  - Una cadena, la colección de estilos de números, el estilo de formato y un `int`.
- La única excepción que lanza es `ArgumentException`.
- Sólo acepta `int`.

`Convert.ToInt32`.

Su objetivo es convertir un valor en un entero de 32 bits desde múltiples tipos de datos.

- Devuelve `int`.
- Tiene 19 sobrecargas.

  - Para convertir `bool`, `byte`, `char`, `DateTime`, `decimal`, `double`, `float`, `int`, `long`, `object`, `sbyte`, `short`, `string`, `uint`, `ulong`, `ushort` a `int`.
  - Para convertir `object` a `int` usando un formato determinado.
  - Para convertir `string` a `int` usando un formato determinado.
  - Para convertir `string` a `int` con una base numérica determinada.
- Lanza tres excepciones: `ArgumentException`, `FormatException`, `OverflowException`.
- Acepta múltiples tipos de datos.

> ¿Es lo mismo hacer A o B?
>
> ```
> /* A */ int.TryParse(DataRow["Zona"].ToString(), out nZona);
> /* B */ int nZona = Convert.ToInt32(DataRow["Zona"].ToString());
> ```

No. Aunque el resultado sea el mismo (el valor de `DataRow["Zona"].ToString()`<sup>1</sup> pasado a `int`) en el caso `A` estás *intentando* hacer la conversión y si no es posible hacerla se te informará con un `false` como retorno mientras que en el caso `B` estás *asumiendo* que la conversión se hará y la única información que recibirás de fallo de conversión será una excepción.

> ¿Que ventajas o desventajas tiene el uno respecto al otro?

`int.TryParse`

- Ventajas:

  - Interfaz más sencilla.
  - Abierto a la posibilidad de fallo, informando del mismo.
  - Específico del tipo de datos.
- Desventajas:

  - Menos flexible.

`Convert.ToInt32`

- Ventajas:

  - Puede convertir desde más tipos de datos.
- Desventajas:

  - Más complejo.
  - No tolera el error, lanza excepción en caso de error.

> ¿En que caso me convendría usar uno en vez de otro?

Usa `TryParse` cuando tengas que convertir desde cadena a un tipo de datos concreto (cada tipo de datos tiene un `TryParse`) y no tengas garantías de que el formato de la cadena sea siempre correcto.

Usa `Convert` cuando tengas garantías de que el tipo de entrada y el tipo de salida son compatibles y la posibilidad de error es nula o muy baja.

> ¿la palabra reservada `out` modifica directamente el valor?

Si y no. No modifica directamente el valor, tan sólo indica que el valor **deberá** ser modificado dentro de la función. Cuando pasas un parámetro como `out` esperas cambiarlo en el cuerpo de la función (y de hecho fallará la compilación si no lo haces).

> ¿Que diferencia hay entre hacer `out variable` o `variable = sentencia`?

En el primer caso, delegas la modificación de la variable a la función a la que pasas la variable, en el segundo caso asignas el valor de la variable el resultado de una sentencia.

---

1. Yo haría `DataRow.Value<string>("Zona")`, pero si sabes que el valor es numérico, no lo conviertas, ¡obtenlo como número directamente!: `DataRow.Value<int>("Zona")`.

Answer (score 2):

En el fondo, [`TryParse`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.2) y [`Convert.ToInt32`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.convert.toint32?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Convert_ToInt32_System_String_) hacen lo mismo: convertir una cadena un entero.

La diferencia fundamental es lo que pasa si la cadena a convertir no es realmente un entero.

Veamos lo que sucede en este caso:

```
int nZona;
string texto = "noesunnumero234";
nZona = Convert.ToInt32(texto);
```

En este caso, como `texto` no contiene una cadena con un entero válido, el programa nos lanza una excepción, [`System.FormatException`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.formatexception?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Veamos que pasa con `TryParse` en la misma situación:

```
bool resultadoConversion=int.TryParse(texto, out nZona);
```

En este caso, no recibimos ninguna excepción. En su lugar, `TryParse` devuelve `false` a `resultadoConversion`, y `nZona` permanece con su valor por defecto, `0`.

Como apunte, no tiene mucho sentido en el código que indicas hacer un `TryParse` sin consultar el valor que devuelve. Evitas la excepción, pero no sabes si la conversión fue correcta. Lo normal es hacer algo como `if (int.TryParse(texto, out nZona)) {..}`.

Personalmente considero que `TryParse` es mucho mas útil a la hora de detectar errores en el casting, ya que no depende de la gestión de excepciones, sino que devuelve un valor booleano que indica si se pudo o no convertir el valor.

En cuanto a [`out`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier), en esta función se utiliza ya que un método en C# solo puede devolver un valor (simplificando, hay otras opciones), y en este caso ya devuelve un `bool` indicando si se pudo o no convertir. Como, además, necesitamos el `int` que es el resultado de la conversión, se usa `out` como modificador del parámetro, que como bien dices, es similar al `ByVal` en basic, e indica que ese parámetro puede ser modificado dentro del método:

> La palabra clave out hace que los argumentos se pasen por referencia. Esto es como la palabra clave ref, salvo que ref requiere que se inicialice la variable antes de pasarla. También es como la palabra clave in, salvo que in no permite que el método llamado modifique el valor del argumento. Para usar un parámetro out, tanto la definición de método como el método de llamada deben utilizar explícitamente la palabra clave out.