# ¿Cómo hacer que un programa pida la edad del usuario y si el usuario no pone nada y solo le da a enter, le vuelva a pedir la edad?

Tags: c#

Estoy tratando de hacer un programa que pida la edad del usuario y si el usuario no ingresa su edad, vuelva a pedirle el dato, el problema es que para que `if(d == "")` funcione, la variable que este en el paréntesis tiene que ser tipo `"string"`, trate de hacer la conversión de `int` a `string` pero no me funciona. Agradecería si me proporcionan alguna idea o solución para este problema.

```
Int32 a;
string d;

do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ingrese su edad ");
            a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


            d = Convert.ToString(a);

            if (d == "")
            {
                    Console.WriteLine("es obligatorio ingresar su edad");
            }
        } while (d == "");
```

Comment: Intenta con el siguiente código  **Convert.ToString(a);** para poder convertir a `String` y realizar la comparación adecuadamente.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Recuerda no decir que no funciono (eso ya lo sabemos) si no decir que errores recibiste en cada uno de tus intentos, para explicarte porque recibiste esos errores.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Podrias entrar en un loop continuo validando si convirte correctamente usando el `TryParse()`

```
int edad;

while(true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Ingrese su edad:");
    string temp = Console.ReadLine();

    if(int.TryParse(temp, out edad))
    {
        break;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("La edad ingresada es invalida, ingrese nuevamente.");
}
```

como veras el `while` esta con true asi solo si convierte aplicas el `break` saliendo del ciclo

Comment: Referencia a [TryParse](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/239739/324)

Answer (score 4):

Utilizando tu mismo código y comentando lo que no es necesario:

```
 //Int32 a;
        string d;

        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ingrese su edad ");
            d = Console.ReadLine();//lo que captura por consola ya es un string

            //d = Convert.ToString(a);

            //if (d == "")
            //{
            //    Console.WriteLine("es obligatorio ingresar su edad");
            //}
        } while (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(d));
```

Esto hace exactamente lo que pides, si el usuario ingresa "enter" en vez de su edad (u cualquier otra cosa), el programa le vuelve a pedir "ingrese su edad". Espero haya sido de ayuda.
El método `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` Indica si la cadena especificada es `null`, está vacía o consta únicamente de caracteres de espacio en blanco.

Comment: estaría bueno reemplazar `d==""` por `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(d)`, para así validar también los espacios en blanco

Comment: @JuanSalvadorPortugal Muy bueno el aporte, no me preocupé de validaciones simplemente para simplificar la respuesta, por eso también utilicé casi el mismo código de Marco

Comment: ya que estamos enseñando.. que la variable no se llame d.. pongamos un nombre tipo.. edadingresada.. o algo que sea descriptivo...

Comment: Igual esto tiene el problema de que en edad, se le puede ingresar "hola" y lo toma como una edad valida.. en ese sentido, la respuesta de Leandro tiene mas sentido...

Comment: @gbianchi Yo solo estoy respondiendo a la pregunta de Marco, en ningún momento el pidió validar la edad.

Comment: Igual.. pero como respuesta, mejor aclarar esas cosas ;)

Comment: @gbianchi Estoy de acuerdo con que la respuesta de Leandro es mejor, solo quise aportar con una respuesta con un código muy similar al utilizado por Marco, creo que así le será mas fácil de entender.

Comment: La respuesta no es mala, y la otra es mas tecnica. Solo te comente algo que a veces es mejor aclarar en la respuesta, aunque sea como comentario al fondo.